# Beautiful soup cannot find specific class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the orange "price" (209,600) found on [this site](https://www.mut.gg/players/3024-mike-haynes/22-13003024/#prices)

It appears to be found in the following div

```
<div class="fs-3 fw-700 text-orange">209,600</div>
```

However, I receive no value when I run the following code.

```
URL = "https://www.mut.gg/players/3024-mike-haynes/22-13003024/#prices"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

price = soup.find_all("div", class_="fs-3 fw-700 text-orange")
print(price)
```

I even tried to manually find element by using `print(soup.prettify())` but it doesn't seem to exist.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It's probably added dynamically by JavaScript. Use Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: you'll find a json here https://www.mut.gg/api/mutdb/prices/22-13003024/xbox-one/ it's the same id than the one in your url so it should be automatable

Comment: @diggusbickus, thanks for the link. I'm new to programming. That link doesn't appear to have any html classes to pull from. How would I go about extracting the number that follows "q2" in that json?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Data you are trying to fetch it is render through JS so what you can
>    try.
> 2. Go to chrom developer mode refresh your website and in Network tab
>    you can search for price and in Fetch/Xhr section you will receive 2
>    links.
> 3. From where data is being update in which you can use 2nd link and it
>    will return data as json

```
import requests
res=requests.get("https://www.mut.gg/api/mutdb/prices/22-13003024/xbox-one/")
data=res.json()['data']['pricesData']['summary']['price']
```

For extracting q2 from `Json`

```
data=res.json()['data']['pricesData']['summary']['q2']
```

Image:

[image]